# Set Google analytics track event with conditional javascript statement

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the below code, and i want to add a script that will pass a track event to GA.
Please note, due to certain restrictions, i cannot place any scripting on the actual code below - i will need to apply it as a seperate standalone script elsewhere on the page.

I just need to know how to put it all together.

The logic I want is

If onclick a.productSizeSelector

AND THEN NOT CLICKING ON any child option under select#ddlSizes

ga('send', 'SizeNotSelected', 'SizeClick', 'Select', 'PDP')

Else if clicking on any child option

ga('send', 'Size (option value eg: M) Selected', 'SizeClick', 'Select', 'PDP')

```
<fieldset class="Frm01 S01">
<label for="ddlSizes">Size</label> <span id="ddlSizesPanel">
<select class=
"productSizeSelector selectBox" id="ddlSizes" name="ddlSizes" onchange=
"javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlSizes\',\'\')', 0)" style=
"display: none;">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">
        please select
    </option>

    <option value="46">
        M
    </option>

    <option value="48">
        XL
    </option>

    <option value="49">
        XXL
    </option>

    <option value="131">
        5XL
    </option>
</select>
<a class="selectBox productSizeSelector selectBox-dropdown" style=
"width: 230px; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0" title=""><span class=
"selectBox-label" style="width: 201px;">please select</span><span class=
"selectBox-arrow"></span></a></span>
```

Comment: Your pseudo-code should help you greatly with doing the actual implementation. You just need to get the `ga('send', 'event', ...)` set correctly. Is that where you are stuck? Sorry, I didn't see an actual question.

Comment: I guess I just need to know how to put it all together.

Comment: Yeah, why don't you try to code it out, and if you get stuck, then post back here with what you've tried. You've got all the right ingredients though.

Comment: With respect - this is why I am asking for help... just need a starting point.

Comment: Would love to help out with the code, so how about if you try your best starting with the pseudo code that you have because once you've got that down, then you're 96% there!